# What are the chrome_drag_* folders in my temp directory?

Tags: google-chrome, temporary-files

Windows 10 - I use Chromiumn browser and other Chromium based software like VS Code on a daily basis.

I routinely see dozens of folders with names like `chrome_drag19184_1885094210` in my `%localappdata%\temp` directory.  In each of the folders, there is a file that I have interacted with during my development.  Is this being caused by Chromium, or VSCode, or something else?  And is it just what it sounds like - a temporary placeholder for a dragged file?

I realize it's not terribly important, but given that finding old versions of files has been extremely helpful several times, I'd like to know under what circumstances these folders get created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's VS Code. If you load multiple documents, split the views and drag one of the documents to another split view, you will see their respective folder update the Last Accessed Date/Time in Explorer.

The PID is in the file name: chrome_drag(PID)_????????

Comment: Thanks.  Exactly what I needed to know.